# Strategy for updating UI while app is backgrounded?

Tags: ios, background, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app that responds to location events when running in the background. When I respond to a location event when the app is backgrounded I am pushing a new view controller onto my UINavigatation controller. This works fine when I trigger only one location event. This allows my user to swipe the notification and viola.. the app launches and the desired view is displayed.

Problems occur after more than one location event occurs. In that situation when I forground the app and the view is all frozen and hung up. I'm assuming the actual ui updates are not occurring in the background and are running as soon as the app is forgrounded and this works ok when there is only one controller pushed onto the nav, but it can't deal with multiple view controller updates.

Do I have this right? And if so.. can someone recommend a good strategy for ensuring that my app forgrounds with the correct view present?

Comment: Unless there is an easier way, I realize I can keep a property of the current view and just tell my UINavController to push that view when the app becomes active.

Comment: I think you are on the right track there. When you get a location event while backgrounded, just save whatever information you need in order to update the UI, but don't do the actual updating until you get for grounded!